# Pass a PhP string to Mootools in Wordpress

Tags: php, string, wordpress, mootools

I have a foreach loop that creates a string in php , I'm unable to pass the string value to mootools in wordpress (I'm integrating a MooTool function ) :::

I need to substitute the "hard coded" image URL's in the **new Array()** (below) with a variable created from my php string eg. new Array( $myimageurl ) :::

I've created a var from the php string even tried json_encode , with no luck :::

```
window.addEvent("domready", function(){
var counter = 0;
var images = new Array('http://localhost/square/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/test-foo/foo.jpg','http://localhost/square/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/test-foo/foo1.jpg');
```

Comment: What does your 'bad' generated JS look like? Nothing? Syntax errors from the inserted text?

Comment: I get the URL's as its above but within this mootools function it's supposed to "seperate" the url's in the items.each(function(item) {  function ::: hope this makes sense

Comment: `var images = json_encode($your_array)` would be the way to go, then. That's evaluate out to `var images = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3' ...]`

Comment: @MarcB This doesn't quite work, each image thats created has a portion of the first images URL eg. h , t, t, p one letter for each image src :::

Comment: Can you past a sample of that into your question. Not sure what you mean.

Comment: You can see a screen-shot here ::: [link](http://goo.gl/hL20g)

Comment: That looks like it's just a string that's being each'd, char by char. What is your source data for those urls? Is it an array? comma-separated string, etc..?

Comment: @MarcB it's a comma-separated string, but I've even used an array no luck as yet ::: **THX for your assistance, I'm going off now will catch you Tomorrow ::: If you have any more ideas I'd appreciate it :::

Answer (score 1, accepted):

er, why not just:

```
var foo= <?=json_encode(Array("foo.jpg", "bar.jpg"))?>;
```

**EDIT**

Since you implied in a comment your files source is comma separated, then do this instead:

```
<? $files = "foo.jpg,bar.jpg"; ?>
var foo = <?=json_encode(explode(',', $files))?>;
```

where the array could be anything of any length, read from wherever. it will result in an array literal looking like so:

```
var foo = ["foo.jpg","bar.jpg"]; 
// eg use. 
foo.each(function(img) {
    new Element("img", {src: img}).inject(document.body);
));
```

nb: just noticed @Marc B has already mentioned json_encode. sorry, will delete

Comment: updated to go in-line with what you commented so it creates an array out of your comma separated string of filenames.

Comment: AH! we have lift-off ::: This works, the only problem I now face is when I run my foreach loop it only gives me my last image ::: But my initial question has been solved, THX to all for the assistance :::

Comment: then you are not looping them correctly, probably. post here some code on how you work with the resulting array for more help.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var images = new Array('<?php echo $miImageUrl[0];?>', '<?php echo $miImageUrl[1];?>');
```

Other way:

```
<?php
//sample data
$descargables[0] = 'cero';
$descargables[1] = 'uno';
$descargables[2] = 'dos';
$descargables[3] = 'tres';
// end sample data

$arrayToJs="var descargables = new Array();";
for ($i=0; $i < count($descargables); $i++) {
    $arrayToJs .= "descargables[" . $i . "]='" . $descargables[$i]. "';";
}

?>

<script>
<?php echo $arrayToJs;?>
idx = 3;
alert("descargable:" + descargables[idx]);
</script>
```

Comment: that will work however the total amount of images are not determined before hand hence the Array should ideally not have this structure :::

Comment: I'll test your suggestion in the morning think I need to carry on when I'm refreshed :::